# Applying tracing options to a redux-thunk setup

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux-thunk, react-devtools

I've recently setup my react native app to use `redux-devtools-extension` and now am trying to figure out how to apply stack tracing. Currently my store is written as so:

```
import reduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducers);

const store = createStore(
  persistedReducer,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(reduxThunk)),
);
```

I basically want to apply the following options so I can see where actions are called from:

```
{
  trace: true, 
  traceLimit: 25,
}
```

Given the above, how can I retrofit my current setup?

Answer (score 4):

The [documentation](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension/blob/master/docs/API/Arguments.md#windowdevtoolsextensionconfig) explains here. I think the file should look like this.

```
import reduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducers);
const composeEnhancers = composeWithDevTools({ trace: true, traceLimit: 25});

const store = createStore(
  persistedReducer,
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(reduxThunk)),
);
```